# Change alembic logger

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

We are using alembic to apply DB revision. I have configured the connection and it works as expected, except I am not able to make it use our customer logger.

We have our own logger class (derived from Python logging) which is used throughout the application, and I want alembic to use it instead of the default.

Is there any way I can pass a logger object of our class to it? I want it to print its own log using the format and handler that is defined in the custom logger.

I tried,

env file

```
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

from tools.logger import Logger

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.attributes.get('configure_logger', True):
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = Logger('alembic.env')
```

my script

```
self.alembic_cfg = alembic_config(self.alembic_ini_path, attributes={'configure_logger': False})
```

I also tried,

```
self.alembic_cfg.set_section_option("logger", "keys", "root")
```

Both of the above methods just disable its own logs.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to **replace** one logger with another. Is it something that you really need though?

> I want it to print its own log using the format and handler that is defined in the custom logger.

As I understand it, logger has handlers and handlers have formatters. If you have a handler with a formatter you could just edit `alembic.ini` and assign your handler to alembic logger.

1. add formatter to formatters in `ini` file

```
[formatters]  # existing section
keys = generic,pyraider  # just add the name of your formatter
```

2. define your custom formatter

```
[formatter_pyraider]
class=tools.logger.PyraiderFormatter
```

3. add handler to handlers in `ini` file

```
[handlers]  # existing section
keys = console,pyraider  # just add the name of your handler
```

4. define your custom handler

```
[handler_pyraider]  # new section, handler_<your_name>
class = tools.logger.PyraiderHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)  # might need to play around with this one
level = INFO
formatter = pyraider
```

5. assign handler to alembic logger

```
[logger_alembic]  # existing section, what you want
level = INFO
handlers = pyraider  # <----  add your handler, defined previously, here
qualname = alembic
```

Docs on `alembic.ini` file.

https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file

You might need to tweak some things but it should work as that's basically how python `logging` module works.

More info on how to structure you `ini` file for logging module
[Official Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format)
[Hitchhiker's Guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#example-configuration-via-an-ini-file)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, as I had exactly the same problem seemingly alembic was ignoring logging configuration I did elsewhere in my code. Actually, logging is configured within `alembic/env.py`:

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

# ...

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
```

Here you can override it with whatever works for you, in effect ignoring the configuration of alembic.ini. I imagine for some it might be easier to integrate this way instead of changing alembic.ini.